# The spaces between positions Different between browsers in RTL

Tags: html, css, height

The spaces between positions Different between browsers
my site is rtl
**in left to right, everything is correct**
**in Firefox, everything is correct** 
in ***IE*** ,***chrome*** and **others** spaces between positions is too high!
The page with the problem can be found [here](http://test.iranlinker.ir/index.php?lang=fa).

Comment: Include relevant code, sufficient for reproducing the issue, in the question itself, and describe exactly what is the expected behavior and how the actual rendering differs.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is this rule:

```
*:after {
   content: "\200E‎";
}
```

in file style-rtl.css line 447.

It looks like Firefox does not recognize this character because when we see this rule in Firefox inspector it looks like:

```
*:after {
    content: "‎‎";
}
```

If you change to:

```
*:after {
    content: "‎‎s";
}
```

You'll see the issue in Firefox too.

So the point is, what does that rule means to you?